# Inputs a sentence from user, determines and displays nonduplicate words in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, linq, var

The official question: Write a console application that inputs a sentence from the user (assume no punctuation), then determines and displays the non-duplicate words in alphabetical order. Treat uppercase and lowercase letters the same. [Hint: You can use string method Split with no arguments, as in sentence.Split(), to break a sentence into an array of strings containing the individual words. By default, Split uses spaces as delimiters. Use string method ToLower in the select and orderby clauses of your LINQ query to obtain the lowercase version of each word.]

This is what I have so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {   // Creates list of type string
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            // Writes for sentence
            Console.Write("Enter your sentence. No punctuation.   : ");
            // Converts console into string
            string sent = (Console.ReadLine());
            // Splits string into array
            string[] words = sent.Split();
            // Writes array to list
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                list.Add(words[i]);
            }
            // Sorts words
            var sort =
                from word in list
                let lowerWord = word.ToLower()
                orderby lowerWord
                select lowerWord;

            // I assume a var query goes here to delete dup words

            // Writes words
            foreach (string c in sort)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }
```

I don't know how to find the duplicates and delete them.

Comment: "The official question:" - erm, what? Is this homework?

Comment: Look into LINQ's group by. That is the best way to find duplicates (or non duplicates as the case may be)

Comment: Mitch: I'm attempting to self teach myself with a few books and I try to go over all the final chapter questions, but this book just doesn't seem very good...

Answer (score 2):

Would

```
var unique = sort.Distinct();
```

work for you?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this works? I've just started learning C#. Would that return a list of just the distinct numbers? Would I not have to use a query?

Comment: From my understanding, 'Distinct()' uses the same default comparison to find the duplicate strings and remove them from the list. In the usage above, it returns a list of strings (the same type as passed in). As for "query", nothing here really qualifies as a query...

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAlphabetizedUniqueWords(string sentence)
    {
        return (sentence ?? string.Empty)
            .Split()
            .Select(x => x.ToLowerInvariant())
            .Distinct()
            .OrderBy(x => x);
    }


    static void Main( )
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your sentence. No punctuation.   : ");
        foreach (var word in GetAlphabetizedUniqueWords(Console.ReadLine()))
            Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After sorting, walk the list, and compare each word to the previous. If they match, delete the word. Since the list is sorted, all the duplicates must be adjacent.

Comment: I thought you could not use boolean (!=) when it comes to strings?

Comment: [String Equality](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-equals) Strings have a .Equals() method.